# I was asked to present a potential course outline for an associate prof. Position. Any advice?

Tags: teaching, data, associate-professor

I applied for an associate professor position in data science and new technologies. It was a real surprise when the committee chose me out of 16 persons to be the first among many.

After 2 weeks of the notification of me being #1, I was asked to present a potential new course in data science on data driven decision making for a master student program.

My teaching expertise is low since I have been doing a lot of research. Would you please advise me what might be helpful when asked such a request? The presentation should be 30 mins and students and staff will be invited to the seminar.

Currently, I am going to include a title, course objectives, learning outcomes, 5-6 modules, and some teaching strategies I will use.

Thank you so much for the helping out. This will be a life changing for me if accepted!

Comment: country and type of university?  (for one thing, it would tell us what 'course' means)

Comment: @AlexanderWoo It is in Europe not in the USA. The university is a public academic university. Department is information systems.

Answer (score 2):

The things you mention are good components of your presentation. Consider adding a slide or two on how your course connects to the rest of the program. In which subsequent courses would you expect specific lessons learned in your course to be useful? What is the prior knowledge your course requires from your students, and where in their program have they acquired this knowledge? You will make a good impression on your future colleagues if you illustrate that your course will be a useful part of a bigger whole.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [suggestions of Wetenschaap](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/178598/75368) consider adding something about student activities (exercises, projects, exams...) and about evaluation. What will student "grades" be based on. Note that the latter may be bound by local custom or rules that you might need to conform to.

Note that students learn by *doing things* not just (or primarily) by listening to lectures.

I don't think you need to be very detailed about exercises and such, but don't omit mentioning evaluation.